# PouchDB quick search: Search within for loop and return results AFTER for loop finish

Tags: for-loop, asynchronous, pouchdb, quick-search

I have the following document structure:

```
{
  "_id": "car_1234",
  "_rev": "1-9464f5d70547c255a423ff8dae653db1",
  "Tags": [
    "Audi",
    "A4",
    "black"
  ],
  "Car Brand": "Audi",
  "Model": "A4",
  "Color": "black",
  "CarDealerID": "5"
}
```

The `Tags` field stores the information of the document in a list. This structure needs to stay like this. Now the user has the opportunity to search for cars in a HTML text input field, where a `,` represents a separation between cars. Let's take the following example:

***black Audi, pink Audi A4***

Here the user wants to find a black Audi or a pink Audi A4. My approach of querying through the database is by splitting the entered words to the following structure `[["black", "Audi"],["pink", "Audi", "A4"]]` and to search inside the `Tags` field of each document in the db if **all** the words in a subarray (e.g. "black" and "Audi") are existent and to return the `CarDealerID`.

```
 ///Before this I return the word list as described
 }).then(function (wordList) {
 results = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < userWords.length; i++) {

    //Check if the object is a single word or an array of words
    if (wordList[i].constructor === Array) {

         //Recreate the words in the array as one string
         wordString = ""
         wordList[i].forEach(function (part) {
             wordString += part + " "
         })
         wordString = wordString.trim()

         //Search for the car
         car_db.search({
             query: wordString,
             fields: ["Tags"],
             include_docs: true
             }).then(function(result) {
                 result.rows.forEach(function (row) {
                    results.push(row.doc.CarDealerID)
                 })
             })

    } else {
       car_db.search({
           query: userWords[i],
           fields: ["Tags"],
           include_docs: true
           }).then(function(result) {
               result.rows.forEach(function (row) {
                  results.push(row.doc.CarDealerID)
               })
           })
    }

    return results

   }).then(function(results) {
         console.log(results)
   }).catch(function (err) {
         console.log(err)
   });
```

### My Problem

My problem is now that the results are returned before the `for` loop finishes. This is probably because it is an async procedure and the result should wait to be returned until this async is finished. But I don't know how to achieve that. I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Nolan Lawson's Blog](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) *(Rookie Mistake #2)* I could figure it out. Instead of the `for` loop, I use

```
return Promise.all(wordList.map(function (i) {
     results = [];
     //
     //Same Code as before
     //
     //Return results inside the map function
     return results;
}));
```